# Insert 1 row but shows 3 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I just want to insert one row with my form but MySQL is showing 3 rows, one of them is mine and two of them is just null.

Here is my code.

**Form**

```
<form method="post" id="contactform" action="iletisim-basarili.php">
        <input type="text" name="isim" placeholder="İsim" class="formcontact"><br>
        <input type="text" name="soyisim" placeholder="Soyisim" class="formcontact"><br>
        <input type="text" name="telefon" placeholder="Telefon Numarası" class="formcontact"><br>
        <input type="text" name="eposta" id="eposta" placeholder="E-Posta Adresi" class="formcontact"><br>
        <input type="text" name="konu" id="konu" placeholder="Konu" class="formcontact"><br>
        <textarea type="text" name="mesaj" id="mesaj" rows="8" placeholder="Mesajınız" class="form--contact--textarea"></textarea><br>
        <div class="validred"></div><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button-form" value="Formu Gönder" />
        </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

        require ('config.php');

        $isim  = trim( $_POST['isim']);
        $soyisim = trim( $_POST['soyisim']);
        $telefon = trim( $_POST['telefon']);
        $eposta = trim( $_POST['eposta']);
        $konu = trim( $_POST['konu']);
        $mesaj = trim( $_POST['mesaj']);

        $kaydet = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO contact SET
        isim  = '$isim',
        soyisim = '$soyisim',
        telefon = '$telefon',
        eposta = '$eposta',
        konu = '$konu',
        mesaj = '$mesaj'
        ");

        if( mysql_affected_rows()) {
        echo "<h3 class='green'>destek talebini kaydettik.</h3><br><h4 class='text'>en kısa sürede"." <b>$destekmail</b>"." üzerinden seninle iletişime geçeceğimizden hiç şüphen olmasın.</h4>";
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Did you submit the form multiple times?

Comment: u need to add this check `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ // your php code }`

Comment: Yes it works :) Thank you so much!

Comment: @AnılKıral: glad to help u

Answer (score 0):

This is function check wather submit button press or its self posted page.So you need to check for submit button.

```
<?php
        require ('config.php');
       //Check before form is submitted.    
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $isim  = trim( $_POST['isim']);
        $soyisim = trim( $_POST['soyisim']);
        $telefon = trim( $_POST['telefon']);
        $eposta = trim( $_POST['eposta']);
        $konu = trim( $_POST['konu']);
        $mesaj = trim( $_POST['mesaj']);

        $kaydet = mysql_query( "INSERT INTO contact SET
        isim  = '$isim',
        soyisim = '$soyisim',
        telefon = '$telefon',
        eposta = '$eposta',
        konu = '$konu',
        mesaj = '$mesaj'
        ");

        if( mysql_affected_rows()) {
        echo "<h3 class='green'>destek talebini kaydettik.</h3><br><h4 class='text'>en kısa sürede"." <b>$destekmail</b>"." üzerinden seninle iletişime geçeceğimizden hiç şüphen olmasın.</h4>";
        }
}

        ?>
```